# Alhazen Billiard problem in 3d

Tags: geometry, billiards

I'm sure that everyone knows what the Alhazen's Billiard problem which is basically determining the point on the edge of a circular billiard table at which a cue ball at a given point must be aimed in order to canon off the edge of the table and hit another ball at a second given point. For my school project I wanted to extend this into a 3d context where the billiard table is spherical and the cue ball and the other ball is within the spherical space, and I am stuck on determining the point on the edge that the cue ball should hit. Does anyone have an idea of what to do?

Comment: Find the plane that contains your two points and the center of the sphere. This will intersect the sphere in a great circle, and then you can use your 2D solution there.

Comment: I tried this approach but I couldn't do the 2d solution on the circle :( because they were 3d coordinates

Comment: You should be able to transform your points to a new coordinate system where all the z coordinates are zero. So I guess the research component of your project will include learning about transforming points between different coordinate systems.